# Batch - How to create a command with set/p and if

Tags: batch-file

i need help for extracting variable from set/p
i explain :

```
set/p command=
:: THE %COMMAND% IS : setname mirtex
if "%command%"=="setname %name%" goto test
:test
echo your name is %name%
```

so i would like to extract my name "mirtex" like the echo mirtex
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split %command% at the first space:

```bat
SET "name=%command:* =%"
ECHO Your name is %name%
```

If your %command% really does have enclosing double quotes add an extra step to remove the closing one.

```bat
SET "name=%command:* =%"
SET "name=%name:~,-1%"
ECHO Your name is %name%
```

Here is a short example based on my comment to your answer:

```bat
:gfn
set/p "fname= Enter your first name "
if "%fname%"=="" goto :gfn
:gsn
set/p "sname= Enter your surname "
if "%sname%"=="" goto :gsn)

set "command=setname %fname% %sname%"
```

Comment: how is the cmd supposed to ask you a question, unless it is running a script?

Comment: sorry i think i have not explained well. i would like to create an command that can be execute directly from the cmd like the command echo [syntax] and but i want to extract the second syntax : echo [first] [second]

Comment: `call script.bat` or `echo %1 %2`

Comment: i rephrase the question : how to extract words from a sentence ...

Comment: Where is the sentence coming from? the command window doesn't just give sentences out for you to work with!

Comment: the sentence coming from me, from the set/p, the sentence is the command : "setname mirtex" the sentence is in the code source.

Comment: just wait a moment i will give you an example with a script

Answer (score 0):

to split a string, a `for` loop is the most flexible way.

I don't know, if you input always will have two elements. If yes:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in (%command%) do (
  set "command=%%a"
  set "name=%%b"
)
echo command is "%command%", name is "%name%"
```

if the number of elements is unknown, best use generic variable names:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p command=
set count=0
for %%a in (%command%) do (
  set /a count+=1
  set "element[!count!]=%%a"
)
echo number of elements: %count%
set element[
```